# Regex statements for date ranges <=4/1/2009 and <=10/01/2009

Tags: regex

I need serious help building two Regex statements for a project. The software we're using ONLY accepts Regex for validation.

I need one that fires for any date <4/1/2009

and a second that fires for any date <10/1/2009

My co-worker gave me the following code to check for <=10/01/2010, but it checks leap years and all that stuff. I need something a little more streamlined than this in the MM/DD/YYYY format. Thanks in advance!

`^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:2[0-9][2-9][0-9])$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:201[1-9])$|^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-|\.)31)|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-|\.)(?:29|30)))(\/|-|\.)(?:201[1-9])$|^(?:(?:(?:11)(\/|-|\.))(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-9]|30)(\/|-|\.))(2010)$|^(?:(?:(?:10|12)(\/|-|\.))(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-9]|30|31)(\/|-|\.))(2010)$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:2[0-9][2-9][0-9])$|^(?:(?:(?:0?[13578]|1[02])(\/|-|\.)31)\1|(?:(?:0?[1,3-9]|1[0-2])(\/|-|\.)(?:29|30)))(\/|-|\.)(?:2[0-9][2-9][0-9])$|^(?:(?:0?[1-9])|(?:1[0-2]))(\/|-|\.)(?:0?[1-9]|1\d|2[0-8])(\/|-|\.)(?:2011)$|^(?:0?2(\/|-|\.)29\3(?:(?:(?:2[0-9][1-9]\d)?(?:0[48]|[2468][048]|[13579][26])|(?:(?:16|[2468][048]|[3579][26])00))))$`

Comment: How far back into the past to you need to be able to go? 20th century? Middle Ages? Before Christ?

Comment: To tail into what Tim said, is there some particular reason you *don't* want to check leap years?  Is there any significance to the dates that would allow more limited scope?  Will the expressions be updated in the future?  (Such as, check for 2010 dates once 2011 rolls around?)

Comment: Furthermore, do you want <= or <? Your question title and text are contradicting each other.

Comment: Maybe the system has a buffer overflow so you can inject some machine code?  ;) j/k

Comment: Why would you use regex for this? Convert the strings to a date format and use whatever methods your language has for comparisons.

Comment: @Ken: the `.` was escaped, but SO was eating the backslash because the OP didn't use code formatting.  It seems the OP only cares about `/`, but if I were supporting all three delimiters I would have written it as `[/.-]`--much more efficient as well as less cluttered.

Comment: @regiereg: can you please update your question to answer the comments above? I.e., must the regex accept a valid date, or only a range and can the date be invalid? Should the regex say "match" when input is `09/01/2010`, or should it say "nonmatch" (i.e.: inclusion vs exclusion vs what you mean with 'fires') or doesn't it matter?

Comment: Also: what is the flavor (Perl, PHP, .NET, XML-Schema etc), because some flavors support numeric ranges or even inline code.

Answer (score 1):

```
^(?:(?:0?2/(?:[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])|0?[13]/(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9]))/2009|(?:0?2/(?:[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])|(?:0?[469]|11)/(?:30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])|(?:0?[13578]|1[02])/(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9]))/(?:200[0-8]|19[0-9]{2}))$
```

will match any date between 1/1/1900 and 3/31/2009, ignoring leap years but otherwise matching only valid dates;

```
^(?:(?:0?2/(?:[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])|0?[469]/(?:30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])|0?[13578]/(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9]))/2009|(?:0?2/(?:[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])|(?:0?[469]|11)/(?:30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])|(?:0?[13578]|1[02])/(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9]))/(?:200[0-8]|19[0-9]{2}))$
```

does the same for 1/1/1900-9/30/2009.

EDIT: It looks like "firing" means "not matching" in your question. So

```
^(?:(?:(?:0?[469]|11)/(?:30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])|(?:0?[578]|1[02])/(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9]))/2009|(?:0?2/(?:[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])|(?:0?[469]|11)/(?:30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])|(?:0?[13578]|1[02])/(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9]))/(?:[3-9][0-9]{2}|2[1-9][0-9]|20[1-9])[0-9])$
```

will match any date from 4/1/2009 onwards, and

```
^(?:(?:11/(?:30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])|1[02]/(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9]))/2009|(?:0?2/(?:[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])|(?:0?[469]|11)/(?:30|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9])|(?:0?[13578]|1[02])/(?:3[01]|[12][0-9]|0?[1-9]))/(?:[3-9][0-9]{2}|2[1-9][0-9]|20[1-9])[0-9])$
```

will match any date from 10/1/2009 onwards.

All regexes created using [RegexMagic](http://www.regexmagic.com).

Comment: Note that these are in DD/MM/YYYY format, not MM/DD/YYYY.  So you'll have to flip a couple things around.

Comment: Note that these also accept nonsensical dates, like "2/29/1985", which the huge regex above tries to reject.

Comment: Thanks I'm on the right track. What I meant was that it would fire (or not allow values <04/01/2009 and <10/01/2009.These sort of work in reverse.  Also I would like to allow anything after these dates though. It craps out if I use a 2010 date. Thanks!

Comment: @Ken: That's what I said - it doesn't validate leap years, as reggiereg clearly wanted. @reggiereg: OK, misunderstood you there - new regexes added.

Comment: That did it! Thanks for your help. i'm gonna invest in a copy of Regexmagic.

Comment: @Ken - the OP doesn't seem to care so much about the dates being valid so much as testing for some specific boundary conditions.